# Akka and Spring Integration comparison

Tags: akka, spring-integration

Was just listening to Josh Suereth's talk "Introduction to Actors Systems" on Devnexus 2013 and got excited. I am familiar with Enterprise Integration Patterns and have Spring Integration experience.

What benefits can Akka provide that Spring Integration can't handle?
Are they competitors or is there any use case where I would like to integrate them?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your feeadback on the matter, first of all!

I'm not familiar with Akka and really not sure it does. Seems for me it is something similar what we have with [Reactor](https://github.com/reactor/reactor).

From other side, if you familiar with Akka and with Spring Integration as well, the contribution is always welcome. We have an [Extension Repo](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-extensions), where you can start a new project on the matter and we will follow with you PoC and go ahead with robust integration.

From other side I know that Apache Cammel has Akka extension (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/java/camel.html), so I don't see reason don't not support it from Spring Integration as well.

Yes, I haven't answered for your original question, but as I know no one from our team is familar with Akka.

Hope someone else share his wisdom here.

Comment: I am not Familiar with Akka nor Reactor and trying to understand why I would like to integrate Akka/Reactor with Spring Integration/Apache Camel